# How do I call a typescript function from a html

Tags: html, typescript

How do I import a typescript function into a html file and call it. I am honestly not sure how to do it.

This is my index.html where I try to call getJSON()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>
    <section id="root"></section>

    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
    ></script>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js").then(reg => {
            console.log("Service worker registered.", reg);
          });
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      const ipc = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        ipc.send("mainWindowLoaded");
        ipc.on("resultSent", (event, arg) => {
          {
            {
              getJSON(JSON.stringify(arg));
            }
          }
          console.log(JSON.stringify(arg));
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my actions.ts

```
export function getJSON(probes: JSON) {
  console.log(probes);
}
```

Comment: Are you using any framework like Angular, Vue, Aurelia, or React? If not, I recommend that you research which one fits best for your needs.

Comment: I am using React @CameronTinker

Comment: Are you using webpack or something to transpile your TypeScript into JavaScript? Do you have a build process?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at [React.Component.componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount). You will be able to set your component's state and update the DOM after fetching your JSON data. The [render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) function takes care of rendering your DOM and will update as your state changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The browser can't understand TypeScript. You will need to transpile it into js. However, you can use a bundler to help you out. But that can be pretty easy.  Checkout https://parceljs.org/